# Raban Gamliel and learning near a pile of gold

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, adult-learning, segulah, gold

I heard that raban gamliel learned near a pile of gold as a segula for something. I'd like to find out if there is a source for this and what it was a segula for

Comment: Like this? "The Minhagei Maharil relates that when Rabbeinu Tam wished to figure out a difficult Halacha he would put in front of himself a pile of gold coins. When seeing the gold he would feel happy. Because of his joy, his mind would expand and he would successfully delve into the depths of our legal tradition with much energy and effort." [PDF](http://content.yutorah.org/viewer/2016/1053/858478.pdf)

Comment: @WAF - Seems like the answer there. Only instead of Rabbon Gamliel it is Rabbeinu Tom...

Comment: @EzraHoerster Could be. Samuel Manuel may have to provide some more information to determine that, and strengthen the question. I'm a _s'gula_ novice at best, but Rabenu Tam could well have taken after Raban Gamli'el.